# Can I assume that Java enumerations auto-increment by 1?

Tags: java, enumeration, ordinal

Java states that the ordinal of the initial value is 0. Can I assume that when I create an enumeration like this :

```
public enum Direction {MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, ...}
```

That the ordinal of `TUESDAY` is always 1, that of `WEDNESDAY` always 2, ...?

---

I'll be a bit more specific. I'm declaring an enumeration :

```
public enum Direction {UP,RIGHT,DOWN,LEFT}
```

Now there's a method to turn 90 degrees (clockwise). It's one line with ordinals :

```
direction = Direction.values()[direction.ordinal()+1 % Direction.values().length];
```

If I wouldn't use ordinals I would have to use switch statements or conditions :

```
switch (direction) {
    case LEFT:newdirection = Direction.UP;
    break;
  etc...
}
```

There are a couple advantages to using ordinals :

- shorter code
- faster code (negligeable)
- if a direction is added (for example `DOWN_LEFT`) the implementation doesn't necessarily have to change if you put the new direction at the right spot

What do you think?

Comment: If it matters (e.g. for custom serialization), you'd be better off with an explicit mapping anyway.  Just create an `EnumMap<Direction, Integer>` or give `Direction` an `int` field.

Comment: I'd rather keep it clean. It's for school, but technically we haven't used enumerations yet, and EnumMap would maybe be a bit extreme since we didn't even learn about arrays yet :D.

Comment: Your notion of clean is a bit misguided :-). Relying on ordinal would be an extremely messy way to code this.

Comment: I don't see why you just don't rely on comparing enums themselves. What are you using this for, exactly?

Comment: My notion of clean is "short and clear". A switch statement with multiple conditions at every case is not as clean as a 2 lines of code. The code is harder to understand, but it's more clean. Hence, if you would throw a bunch of stuff in your room, it would be messy. If you only throw 2 small things in it, it's still clean.

Comment: @AHungerArtist : because it's for school, and I'm a perfectionist. Relying on ordinals would make my code way shorter and faster too (sure its only a ms but still, it's a ms).

Comment: It's funny, you say "short and clear" then say the code is harder to understand. One 1/10000 of a millisecond is usually nowhere near as valuable as making something understandable and maintainable. If you're a perfectionist, you must consider more than negligible optimization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29):

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero).

Comment: I don't understand : this only states the ordinal of the initial constant is zero, not that the second constant has ordinal 1, or that the third constant has ordinal 2, ...

Comment: @Korion "its position in its enum declaration", starting from 0. So MONDAY.ordinal() == 0, TUESDAY.ordinal() == 1 etc.

Answer (score 7):

Yes - but your code should not rely on it because then it will break when someone inserts Caturday.

Comment: True, but the enumeration will always remain the same in my case.

Comment: You're right :D. My enumeration is actually {UP,RIGHT,DOWN,LEFT} but I guess technically the teacher could bug me and add directions like DOWN_LEFT, UP_RIGHT, ...

Comment: I hope your teacher does. It would be a good learning lesson :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, however, relying on this makes your code brittle. If you ever change the order of the constants in the enum or add constants between them, the ordinals of some of the constants will change. So, it is for example not a good idea to store ordinal numbers in a database or a file, because if your source code changes, the data in the database or file will not be compatible anymore with your changed code.

A more robust solution is to explicitly store codes with each of your constants. For example:

```
public enum Status {
    NEW(0),
    PROCESSING(1),
    OK(2),
    ERROR(99);

    private final int code;

    private Status(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    // Get the code for an enum constant
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    // Given a code, get the corresponding enum constant
    public static Status fromCode(int code) {
        for (Status s : Status.values()) {
            if (s.code == code) {
                return s;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid code: " + code);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also enforce indexes like this:

```
enum Direction {
  MONDAY(1),
  TUESDAY(2);
  // etc...

  private int value;    

  private Direction(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. However, relying on that is not the best idea if you ever want to reorder or add new enums in different places, or if you find a reason to change an existing value. I find it better to give them an actual value/meaning aside from their ordinal value and name.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. As I'm using a standard enum like the one above that will never change it's contents, I guess I'll make the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with ordinals is that they depend on the order of declaration of the enum values. If at some point a new value is added to the enumeration, and it's added in the middle of the others, then the ordinals will change, invalidating all code that depended on a specific ordinal value.

If you absolutely must assign a fixed number to an ordinal value, this might be of use:

```
enum Directions {
    NORTH(1),
    SOUTH(2),
    WEST(3),
    EAST(4);
    private int code;
    Directions(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

In the above snippet, a `code` attribute is associated to each enumeration value, and you can be sure that it will always have the same value - the one passed in the constructor.